# Scala & Slick: type mismatch with [Product with Serializable] needs to be fixed

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am trying to implement a method that retrieves all the users by reusing a method that retrieves a single user based on the userID, but can’t figure out the type mismatch. Would you tell me how to fix this?

UserDAOImpl.scala:

```
def findAll: Future[Seq[User]] = {
  val dbUsers: Future[Seq[DbUser]] = db.run(users.result)

  dbUsers.map { dbUserSeq =>
    dbUserSeq.map { dbUser => find(UUID.fromString(dbUser.userID)).value.get match {
      case Success(Some(usr: User)) => usr
      case _ => None
    }}
  }
}
```

I’ll omit the definition of `find` since it works fine, but here’s the signature.

```
def find(userID: UUID): Future[Option[User]] = {
```

Error message:

```
found   : Seq[Product with Serializable]
required: Seq[models.User]
          dbUserSeq.map { dbUser =>
                        ^
```

Just in case, the definition of users

```
private val users = TableQuery[UserTable]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn;'t seem to relate to slick but to your code only. ffind(UUID.fromString(dbUser.userID)) returns a future so you probably need ot flatmap over that?

Comment: You already have all users, no? It's here *val dbUsers: Future[Seq[DbUser]] = db.run(users.result)*

Comment: @Edmondo1984 `case Success(Some(usr: User)) => usr` part does that. Thanks for the reply, though.

Comment: @Artavazd Balayan `Future[Seq[User]] not Future[Seq[DbUser]]` is what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-blocking approach:

```
def findAll: Future[Seq[User]] = {
  db.run(users.result)
    .map(dbUserSeq =>
      Future.sequence(dbUserSeq.map(dbUser => find(UUID.fromString(dbUser.userID))))
    )
    .flatMap(userFutSeq => // userFutSeq is a Future[Seq[Option[User]]]
      userFutSeq.map(userSeq => userSeq.collect { case Some(u) => u })
    )
}
```

The above code gathers the users that are found and ignores the rest.

Avoid using `Await` except for testing purposes. When working with futures, stay within the context of a `Future`.

Comment: Thank you for the great tip. I knew using Await was not a good idea, but without it, couldn’t figure out how. Just One thing: The code you posted actually didn’t compile, saying "value flatten is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[models.User]]], maybe a semicolon is missing before `value flatten’?” But if I replace the map with flatMap, It compiles. Do you have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: @hirofujitaaki: You're probably getting the error because you're using a pre-2.12 version of Scala; `flatten` was added to the `Future` API in Scala 2.12. Having said that, `flatMap` is a better approach, so I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, so I shouldn't worry about it that much. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

The previous code actually had several problems, and the code below is the solution I came up with so far. Maybe not the simplest, but it worked.

```
  def findAll: Future[Seq[User]] = {
    db.run(users.result).map { dbUserSeq =>
      dbUserSeq.map { dbUser =>
        val userFut: Future[Option[User]] = find(UUID.fromString(dbUser.userID))
        Await.ready(userFut, Duration.Inf).value.get match {
          case Success(Some(usr: User)) => usr
          case _ => throw new RuntimeException
        }
      }
    }
  }
```